# What type of tree is this?

Tags: identification, trees

What type if tree is this growing in Toowoomba, Australia in mid-spring?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If it is Robinia pseudacacia, its the variety 'frisia' and it should have the odd thorn or two here and there on the trunk or branches

Comment: It doesn't appear to have any thorns anywhere,  and there are no flowers (yet?}

Comment: IF it flowers, they're white pea like flowers in racemes in early spring, but this tree isn't exactly free flowering and you may not get any anyway. If you do, that would confirm the ID of Robinia - I'm not 100% it is that, but can't think of anything else it might be at the moment, and this plant is very similar

Answer (score 5):

From the pictures you have posted, it might be a *Robinia* (aka black locust, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinia_pseudoacacia).
It is native to northern America but reportedly naturalized in eastern Australia.
Pictures of a flower would be helpful for identifying with confidence, as would be a close-up of stipule and stem.

Comment: You can also feel around the trunk and see if it has thorns. They might be pretty small and in the cracks of the bark, but all acacias real or psuedo have thorns. Some 4 inches long, some on a 1/4 inch and barely noticeable except on newly hardened off wood or in the cracks of the bark.

Comment: Almost 4 months later, and I've not seen/felt any thorns on the trunk, nor has the tree flowered. Could this still be a Robinia?